# Including a persons name and last name in a url, battling with the space

Tags: php, html, url

I'm pretty new to this and need a hand
I'm trying to send out personalised greetings. My code works perfectly as long as the names of the sender and beneficiary are limited to their first names. As soon as I input their last names the URL doesn't include it, I'm guessing that the issue is because of the space between their first and last names.
The php data comes from an input on my website

here is a sample of my code

```
<p>Dear <?php echo stripslashes($item -> iof_benname); ?></p>
<p></p>
<p>A donation has been made in your honour by: <?php echo stripslashes($item -> iof_name); ?></p>
<p></p>

 <p>Please <a href=http://myym.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IHO.php?NAME=<?php echo stripslashes($item -> iof_name)?>&BNAME=<?php echo stripslashes($item -> iof_benname) >>click here</a> to view your message.</p>
```

Comment: Add quotes around your `href` -> `<a href="http://myym.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IHO.php?NAME=<?php echo stripslashes($item -> iof_name)?>&BNAME=<?php echo stripslashes($item -> iof_benname) ?>">`.

Comment: Thanks Sean, works perfectly. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

First, sanitization should be handled with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), not `stripslashes`.

Second, parameters in URLs like that should be escaped with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode).

Comment: I first tried Sean's suggestion above and it works perfectly. Should I still move away from the stripslashes?

Comment: @byraff Sean's suggestion will help for the same reasons `urlencode` would - there's a space in your URL. Not having quotes around it meant the browser didn't know if the space was in the URL or a new attribute. Quotes help, and `urlencode` would help by turning the space into something like `%20`. As for `stripslashes`, probably. It's a very outdated technique and probably doesn't do what you think it does.